# php regex not ending with 'C'

Tags: php, regex

I can get the correct regex to find all the strings that contain "TB" + 8 numbers and doesnt end with "C"

This should match: **TB12345678**
This shouldn't match **TB12345678C**

My PHP code is:

```
$this->tbTrabajadores = preg_grep('/^TB([0-9]{8})[^C]/', $this->tablas);
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `TB12345678G` that one should match? or you want only thoses without any letter at the end, can you have `TB12345678EIUHRIUR`? Please show us several case to have a better idea of the regex you need.

Comment: I only have 2 possible cases... table names with and without C no other letters are present

Comment: Use $ at the end: ...[^C]$/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation in the end:

```
$this->tbTrabajadores = preg_grep('/^TB\d{8}([^C]|$)/', $this->tablas);
```

`([^C]|$)` will match either a non-C char or line end.

You can also use a negative lookahead after matching 8 digits:

```
/^TB\d{8}(?!C)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK9eG9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$str  = 'TB12345678Cddd';
preg_match_all('/^TB([0-9]{8})/', $str, $a);
var_dump($a);
```

[enter link description here](https://eval.in/636594)